# permission denied error trying to run custom script, but works in SSHDroid

Tags: root-access, usb, shell, superuser

I wrote this script to reset a USB controller:

```
echo -n '1-2' | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
sleep 0.5
echo -n '1-2' | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

I can then run it like so:

```
q201:/data # sh foobar.sh
1-21-2q201:/data #
```

But I cannot run it like this:

```
q201:/data # su -c "sh /data/foobar.sh"
tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind: Permission denied
1-2tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind: Permission denied
1-2
1|q201:/data #
```

It only works when I am connected to SSHDroid on my rooted device, other apps such as Kernel Adiutor, Script Manager fail to run the script and get the same permission denied error that I get when I try to run it with su.

The su binary that came with my android device does not prompt to grant permission. It just gives it to any apps that ask.

I just want this script to run via other apps, and/or on startup.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with SELinux, and upon further digging, it seems I had to adjust the permissions of these files to make this work. I don't really understand it, but it seems to work.

```
chmod 644 /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
chmod 644 /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind

echo -n '1-2' | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
sleep 0.5
echo -n '1-2' | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind

chmod 200 /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
chmod 200 /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```